# OpenCv QT CvNamedWindow IplImage not working

Tags: qt, visual-c++, opencv

I have problem with displaying Cam on QTLabel using openCV,
  Every thing is working fine . except one . I have to call function from open === cvNamedWindow() == in order for program to work properly . its displaying the webcam on the QLabel no problem but if i don't call the cvNamedWindow function then the program is just hanging its just keep displaying the camera which are working on the screen but i can't click on any thing else its getting freeze. Does any one has any idea why its happening and what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the Qt event loop by calling

```
app.exec();
```

?  Otherwise the Qt events such as mouse clicks will never be handled.

If you have your code in a loop requesting the camera images frame by frame, you can also call

```
qApp->processEvents();
```

.  Maybe you can post the relevant code snippet, otherwise it's hard to say what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.. That how my application is kicking off.. This is main method

TryQt is my Application with GUI....

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QString path = qApp->applicationDirPath();
a.addLibraryPath(path+"/plugins");
TryQt w;
w.show();
return w.exec();
```